# How to use permission with signature protection?

Tags: android, android-permissions

I want to learn how to create a main application and its associated key application. The problem is I don't know how to make key application broadcast mainapp.action.VALID into main app.

### @MainApp

```
<permission
        android:name="mainapp.permission.CHECK_RESULT"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<application>

    <receiver
        android:name=".ResponseReceiver"
        android:permission="mainapp.permission.CHECK_RESULT" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="mainapp.action.CHECK_OK" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

### @KeyApp

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction("mainapp.action.CHECK_OK");
context.sendBroadcast(i, "mainapp.permission.CHECK_RESULT");
```

The result is, intent is rejected: it requires mainapp.permission.CHECK_RESULT permission. But If I remove the permission, mainapp.receiver.ResponseReceiver can receive the intent and also can confirm that both app use the same signature.

What do I miss here?

Comment: have you added uses-permission tag?

Answer (score 2):

As nandeesh indicates, you need the corresponding `<uses-permission>` element in your KeyApp, saying that KeyApp requests the `mainapp.permission.CHECK_RESULT` permission.

Also, AFAIK, your second parameter to `sendBroadcast()` will require MainApp to also have the `<uses-permission>` element for `mainapp.permission.CHECK_RESULT`. If that is not your intent (pun intended (nested pun intended (oh, no! infinite pun recursion!))), I would drop that second parameter on the `sendBroadcast()` call.

Comment: You're right that I missed <uses-permission> on KeyApp. I don't need to use permission string when calling sendBroadcast. It works like charms! Thanks!